# use cvtColor in a loop

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to run in a loop the cvtColor command.

```
    vector<Mat> RImages;
    vector<Mat> hImages;      

    for ( int idx = 0; idx < blocks_width * blocks_height; idx++ )
    {
        ...
        Mat temp;
        RImages.push_back( imread( filename , 1 ) );
        hImages.push_back( cvtColor( RImages[ idx ], temp , CV_BGR2HSV ));
    }
```

I am receiving error:

> invalid use of void expression
>   in ctColor.

Comment: `cvtColor` returns `void`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cvtColor( RImages[ idx ], temp , CV_BGR2HSV )
```

This function does not return anything. the result of the cvtColor is stored in the temp. Your code should be like this:

```
vector<Mat> RImages;
vector<Mat> hImages;      

for ( int idx = 0; idx < blocks_width * blocks_height; idx++ )
{
    ...
    Mat temp;
    RImages.push_back( imread( filename , 1 ) );
    cvtColor( RImages[ idx ], temp , CV_BGR2HSV );
    hImages.push_back(temp  );
}
```

BTW, you can optimise your code a bit like this:

```
vector<Mat> RImages;
vector<Mat> hImages;
RImages.reserve(blocks_width * blocks_height); 
hImages.reserve(blocks_width * blocks_height); 
for ( int idx = 0; idx < blocks_width * blocks_height; idx++ )
{
    ...
    Mat temp;
    RImages.emplace_back(imread( filename , 1 ) );
    cvtColor( RImages[ idx ], temp , CV_BGR2HSV );
    hImages.emplace_back(temp  );
}
```

Comment: Welcome, do not forget to accept if it was helpful ;)

Comment: It's better to insert the temp image into the vector with `temp.clone()`.  You can also optimize further like: `vector<Mat> himages(blocks_width * blocks_height); for(...) {... cvtColor(Rimages[idx], himages[idx], ...);}`

Comment: I disagree a bit about temp.clone(). why?

Comment: In this case is ok, since temp is declared inside the loop. If you declare it _outside_ the loop, the vector himages won't be correct. So, with "better", I meant "safer". You already have my plus one

Comment: Yes totaly agree due to the shallow copy of Mat in case of outter temp. Thanks